# VBA to move Email from Inbox to a Created Default/Parent Folder (Not a Subfolder) in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, directory, parent

We have a folder in Outlook named "Reports" that was actually created on the same level as the default folders in Outlook (i.e. Inbox, Drafts, Sent Items, etc.)

Most of the tutorials out there only show how to access created Subfolders from a default parent folder, but not how to access created folders on the same parent level. I need a script that moves emails from our "Inbox" to another parent level folder called "Reports".

Here's the general code:

```
Sub MoveItems()

Dim NewApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set NewApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = NewApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItems = myInbox.Items
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Kevin Feige'")

Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Reports")

While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
myItem.Move myDestFolder
Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Obviously, it errors out with Set = myDestFolder because it's treating "Reports" as a subfolder inside the default Inbox. The VBA run-time error by the way is 2147221233 (8004010f). I even tried if I could get the enumerations for the olDefaultFolders property with no luck.

Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thank you.